# Usar Destroy com FindGameObjectsWithTag

Tags: c#, unity-5

Estou desenvolvendo um jogo pela Unity e gostaria que música tema do jogo continuasse nas trocas de cenas mas parasse em determinada cena. Para a música continuar eu usei o  **DontDestroyOnLoad** e tudo certo, mas não consigo conectar ao **FindGameObjectsWithTag**. Alguém poderia me ajudar? Pfv

Comment: Olá, Gabriel, seja bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! O que você tentou até agora? É importante você incluir em sua pergunta um [Exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1186/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-completo-e-verific%c3%a1vel) para mostrar onde você está com dificuldade e facilitar a reprodução e identificação de uma solução para o problema.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, Gabriel.

Você está usando FindGameObjectsWithTag para encontrar classe gerenciadora de áudio, certo?

Te aconselho a usar o padrão de projeto Singleton. Veja um exemplo:

```
public class SoundManager
{
   static SoundManager instance;

   static SoundManager Instance
   {
      get
      {
         if (instance == null)
            instance = FindObjectOfType<SoundManager>();

         return instance;
      }
   }
}
```

Agora, você pode encontrar a referência para o SoundManager acessando SoundManager.Instance. Lembrando que continua sendo necessário utilizar o DontDestroyOnLoad no Awake ou Start.

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

Gabriel, no que mencionou tu usaste o **FindGameObjectsWithTag** isso irá retornar um Array de objetos, o que parece não ser o caso, tu queres a musica tema que estará atrelado em um unico GameObject com um unico Source, neste caso lhe indico a usar o **FindGameObjectWithTag**.

Tu consegues utilizar ambos sem maiores problemas, na tua cena principal, onde estará a musica tema, aplique o seguinte código no teu start:

```
void Start()
{
    DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
}
```

Após isso em tua outra cena, notarás que aparecerá algo parecido com isso aqui:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esta imagem de exemplo é só para mostrar que a Unity separa a cena e mostrará qual os GameObjects das quais não foram destruídas. Na tua segunda cena no GameObject do qual farás o controle do AudioSource não destruído, execute o seguinte código no Start:

```
[SerializeField] private GameObject source;

void Start()
{
    source = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Inforar aqui a tag do seu GameObject");
}
```

Caso esteja com a tag corretamente destinada ao GameObject ele irá efetuar o Find Corretamente, como no exemplo a seguir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por se tratar de uma String, verifique se está com a tag digitada corretamente